# multibranchPipelineJob job DSL: how to enable Discover branches and Suppress automatic SCM triggering

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl, multibranch-pipeline

How to enable in a Jenkins job DSL for a multibranch pipeline the behavior **Discover Benches** and the Property strategy **Suppress automatic SCM triggering**?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
multibranchPipelineJob('job name') {
    branchSources {
        branchSource {
            source {
                git {
                    remote('https://<repo address>.git')
                    credentialsId('credential id')
                }
            }
            strategy {
                defaultBranchPropertyStrategy {
                    props {
                        noTriggerBranchProperty()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    configure {
        def traits = it / sources / data / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' / source / traits
        traits << 'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait' {}
    }
    triggers {
        periodic(2) // Trigger every 2 min.
    }
    orphanedItemStrategy { discardOldItems { numToKeep(-1) } }
}
```

Comment: Roberto, can you explain the closure in the body of your configure {} clause? E.g. what are "it" and "sources" and "data"? I'm trying to use the configure {} clause in a multibranch pipeline job to define a job's labels (for all branches) since labels aren't currently supported in jobdsl: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-63789

Answer (score 3):

Just to extend the accepted answer: you don't necessary need that tricky `traits << ...` syntax to add branch (or tags) discovery. Instead you may use `traits { }` section (see [docs](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/multibranchPipelineJob)).

```
multibranchPipelineJob 'job name', {
    branchSources {
        branchSource {
            source {
                git {
                    id 'job name'
                    remote 'git@<repo-url>.git'
                    credentialsId 'git-creds-id'

                    traits {
                        gitBranchDiscovery()
                        gitTagDiscovery() // if you need tag discovery
                    }
                }
            }
            strategy {
                defaultBranchPropertyStrategy {
                    props {
                        noTriggerBranchProperty()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but the docs only mention the "branchSources > git" API. I don't see anything about the "branchSources > branchSource > source > git" API. It does work but is this public API or is it internal API?